# Spring mvc web app with spring security login - how to pass credentials to cxf STS client for service integration?

Tags: web-applications, spring-security, cxf, sts-securitytokenservice

I have a web app that uses spring security to log in. I am trying to integrate a backed service using cxf which uses STSClient. Is there a reference implementation for integrating the two? I've tried creating my own authentication provider that will take the username and password, stick them into the stsclient and then make a service call to validate the credentials from the same IDP/SP as the service but I still seem to have issues with multiple sessions sharing the same cxf credentials. I've hacked for a while and don't have a clean sample to post yet but would appreciate a tutorial if there's one out there.